# After viewing web in app, cannot return to app without closing it and relaunching

Tags: xcode, webview

I have an app which has several different buttons leading to various views. One of the views will open a website in Safari on iPhone which is what I want to happen. THe problem is that if I then want to go back to the app, all I get is a white screen, and I have to double click on home button, close the app and relaunch it.

Would this relate to releasing memory or view perhaps? I'm not sure how to go about fixing it so after viewing the web page in safari I can then go back to the app and continue with other views.

Here is what I am using in webViewController.m

```
#import "webViewController.h"
@interface webViewController ()
@end
@implementation webViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
NSURL *url = [ [ NSURL alloc ] initWithString: @"http://www.mydomain.com" ];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use webView to load this url, then you can make a back button on this webview to come back to your app without leaving the app.

```
UIWebView * webView =[[UIWebView alloc]init];

webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[webView setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 51, 320, 398)];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mydomain.com"];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView setDelegate:self];
webView loadRequest:requestObj];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

You can also use some delegate methods of webView to know whether your page has been loaded or not

```
-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{


}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{

}

-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, the reason I was opening the link in Safari rather than in a webView within the app is that the webpage doesn't fit and you have to scroll to view it all. If I could figure out a way to make the webpage fit, then that would solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ah I've figured it out, I've added

```
web view.scalesPagesToFit = Yes
```

statement and opening the webpage in the webview works exactly how I wanted it to.